# Changing background color of only one id instead of all

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out a way to create a tic tac toe game for school and I'm stuck. I'm trying to change the background color of the div I click on using an if else if. It sort of works but instead of changing the BG color of each individual square I clicked, all 9 squares change colors. If I change the "boxes[i]" to "this", I get an "undefined" and the code only puts an x or an o.

```
    var turns = 'X';
    var xColor = "#1772e8";
    var oColor = "#e15258";

    function changeColor() {
        var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
        for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i += 1) {
          if( turns === 'X' ) {
               boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = oColor;
          } else {
               boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = xColor;
          }
        }
    }

function click() {
        if ( this.id === "box1" ) {
          if (document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML === ""){ 
               document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = turns;
               changeTurn();
               changeColor();
          }
     }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you call `changeColor()`?

Comment: Please provide your html code and how you call your javascript function

Comment: Oh yeah, with a click() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting every single .box element on the page, which is why they are all changing.

I would try something like this (assuming that you are calling changeColor() from an onClick):

HTML:

```
<div class="box" onclick="changeColor(this)"> </div>
```

JS:

```
function changeColor(clickedBox) {
    if( turns === 'X' ) {
         clickedBox.style.backgroundColor = oColor;
    } else {
         clickedBox.style.backgroundColor = xColor;
    }
}
```

By passing the clicked box to the function you know the exact box you have to deal to (note that we pass "this" in the onClick definition, which is why your earlier attempts at using "this" came out as undefined).

EDIT:
[Here is an example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNyyBO)

Comment: Holy hell! That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Let me implement your help with my code. Thank you so much Olly F-G! You the man.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is ok, do this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").click(function(){
    //If else statement here
    $(this).css("background-color","[color of your choice]");
  }
});
```

Comment: We're still learning vanilla javascript. Next week we'll get to play with jQuery. Thanks for the reply James.